# Node.js smb2 package for accessing data on share of Windows Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

Marry Christmas to everyone.

I have a my project, which should have file manipulation of Windows Sever File share which located on different Server, than my portal.

I tried to use *npm install smb2* for accessing to directories and files.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/smb2

But I got strange error:
`node:internal/crypto/cipher:121 this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength); forge.js:20:24) { library: 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' }`

My code:

```
const smb2Client = new smb2({
  share: "\\\\192.168.200.195\\Departments",
  domain: "CHILDER",
  username: "lukyanena.ar",
  password: "password",
});

smb2Client.readdir("/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  files.forEach((file) => {
    console.log(file.filename);
  });
});
```

I have latest version of node.js 20.10.00 LTS

If there is another way to access data on Windows File Share, please tell me.

1. Check and update node.js
2. Use another type cipher encryptionMethod: "aes-128-cbc",
3. Contanct System Administrator, he said there is no encryption there, it is your fault :(

Comment: Forgive me the question, but why dont you let handle the OS the smb/file system stuff, and just use the node fs module to do what ever you want on the smb share?

Comment: @Marc, I tried that too but it does not do nothing just throw error to by not be able get data 

fs.readdir(smbSharePath, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  // Filter directories only
  const directories = files.filter(file => {
    const filePath = path.join(smbSharePath, file);
    return fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory();
  });

  console.log('Directories in the SMB share:');
  directories.forEach(directory => {
    console.log(directory);
  });
})

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information. What OS are you using? Can you access the mount point via the OS tools and show its content? If that works, then it have also to work in node.js